# CS0119 in compiling C#, Error at Task parameters

Tags: c#

I've been working on a Discord Bot, and I get a really bad error.

I'm a beginner. I'm sorry if it's a dumb error, I probably didn't even knew C# basics more than a month ago.

```cs
private async Task Filter(SocketMessage arg)
{

}

public async Task StartInterpretation()
{
    await Filter(SocketMessage arg);
}
```

This is a small example that makes the error i'm getting. the `await Filter(SocketMessage arg)` causes this error:

> error CS0119: 'SocketMessage' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

(the error is something with parameters as i can see.)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0119

Comment: One: you are NOT initializing `arg`.  Secondly, you don't use a type parameter when calling a method.  so `await Filter(SocketMessage arg)` needs to change to `await Filter(arg)`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to initialize arg, then pass into the Filter function. Something like:

```
public async Task StartInterpretation()
{
    var arg= new SocketMessage();
    await Filter(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CS0119` compilation error is specifically because you are putting in a type parameter when you call a method.  That's not allowed, it's only when declaring a method do you specify the type that it should expect.

However you have another issue where you are not instantiating `arg`.  Below is your code updated so that it would compile.

```cs
// this is correct, SocketMessage is the type parameter that Filter expects
private async Task Filter(SocketMessage arg)
{

}

public async Task StartInterpretation()
{
    var arg = new SocketMessage();
    // do not specify the type parameter, just pass the variable
    await Filter(arg);
}
```